Docker restarting containers on reboot when shut down
I've been playing around with Docker for the past few months. I've created several docker-compose.yml files and have a handful of services running. I'm at the point where I'm finalizing my setup. I have about 5 services that I have running but I tested about 20. Of those, I have about 9 starting every time I restart the server.
I use docker compose to start and stop my containers. I've done everything I can think of but I have a few that will start up every time I restart no matter what I do.
My system setup:
Ubuntu 24.04 Workstation with public ip 
Docker v27.2.0 using docker compose files

An example of a few auto starting:
Portainer
Apprise
vscode

This is my portainer docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer-ee:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}    
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9443:9443'
    volumes:
        - ${TG_DIR_DATA}/portainer:/data
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: no
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - tgnetwork
volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  tgnetwork:
    external: true

I've done the following without any success:
docker compose stop
docker compose down
docker stop portainer

But they continue to start.
Anyone have any suggestions on how to control which containers start on system restart?
Thanks all!
